# REST webapi URI GET with string instead of id not routing as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have the following example where the request is `http://{domain}/api/foo/{username}` but I get a 404 status code back. No other Get actions exist on this controller. Shouldn't this work?

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    public Foo Get(string username)
    {
      return _service.Get<Foo>(username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default your route will look something like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When you visit the url `http://{domain}/api/foo/{username}` the controller is mapped as `foo` and the optional `id` parameter is mapped to `{username}`. As you don't have a Get action method with a parameter called `id` a 404 is returned.

To fix this you can either call the API method by changing the URL to be explicit about the parameter name:

```
http://{domain}/api/foo?username={username}
```

Or you could change your parameter name in your action method:

```
public Foo Get(string id)
{
    var foo = _service.Get<Foo>(username);
    return foo;
}
```

Or you could change your route to accept a `username`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{username}",
    defaults: new { username = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: changing the parameter name doesn't fix it. I double checked that there is only the defaultapi route also. If I make the parameter an int, then it works but I need it to be a string.

Comment: I see the issue why it doesn't work with a string, I'm passing an email as the username and even encoded it doesn't like it. What's interesting, if I do /{username}/something it works if I add [Route("api/foo/{username}/something")

Comment: This worked for me. I change the get parameter int id to a string guid and changed the route in RouteConfig. I also changed the WebApiConfig route from id to guid.