# Search by email not id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-routing

We know that Asp.net Web API 2 has the api/get/5 method for searching by id. I need to search by email, and I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329724/rest-webapi-uri-get-with-string-instead-of-id-not-routing-as-expected) where I need a simple example rather. I also looked into Angularjs routing and I found that topic needs time from where I have to finish this today.

Part of my controller for the api/users/5.

```
// GET: api/users/5         get user by id
    public Users Get(int id)
    {
        Users user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return user;
    }
```

My JS code

```js
 $http.get('/api/users'+ $scope.Email)
         .success(function (response) {
             $scope.users = response;
         });
```

Thank you

Comment: 404 (Not Found).
Although the email is there in the db

Answer (score 1):

try passing email as the parameter.

```
public Users Get(string Email)
    {
        Users user = db.Users.Find(Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: 404 (Not Found). Although the email is there in the db

Comment: try checking for case sensitive ToLower() for the email or debug the code and check where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot '/' in $http call

```
$http.get('/api/users/'+ $scope.Email)
         .success(function (response) {
             $scope.users = response;
         });
```

And Asp :-

```
public Users Get(string Email)
    {
        Users user = db.Users.Find(Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Hope it helps not sure :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
404 (Not Found). Although the email is there in the db