# ASP WebApi GET response with string id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a question.

I have a table of users. ID of user is a `string`. I have GET that looks like that:

```
    // GET: api/WatchedProduct
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WatchedProduct> GetWatchedProduct(string id)
    {
        var productsList = id == String.Empty ?
            db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == id).ToList() :
            db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == loggedUserId).ToList();

        return productsList;
    }
```

When i call API in Postman, i get this response:

```
{
"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://.../api/WatchedProduct'.",
"messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'WatchedProduct' that matches the request."
}
```

My question is, how to make `GetWatchedProduct` method like when `id` is `int` (`GetWatchedProduct(int? id)`) ? Is it possible to do the same with a string? I need another Get Method?

**EDIT:**

When i call my API with string param:

```
http://localhost.../api/WatchedProduct/StringidHere
```

It works, I want to have one method for GET in my controller. When `String.Empty` and when i pass a string.

My `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

`WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        /*var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        cors.SupportsCredentials = true;

        config.EnableCors(cors);*/

        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**EDIT3:**

For example, that method from another controller works:

```
     // GET: api/Product/search?str=kaarol
    [Route("search")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetSearch(string str)
    {
        return db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(str)).ToList();
    }
```

But in my case, i want to have one method to call `/Api/Watched...` and with `StringID` when i want to.

Comment: How your Route.config look like?

Comment: Im using Controllers generated from scaffold (Webapi2 Read/Write based on EF)

Comment: try with default value:`string id = ""` or `string id = null`

Comment: string cannot be nullable

Comment: look into my edit

Comment: Try this attribute `[Route("api/WatchedProduct/{id}")]` and make sure that you have `defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }`.

Comment: Try posted answer if the problem still persists then post the `WebApiConfig` file?

Comment: Look into edit now

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i added another edit that might be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally your route works like `GET /api/controllerName/` If you want to access it like `GET /api/controllerName/customRoute` you need to Route your method.

```
// GET: api/WatchedProduct
[HttpGet]
[Route("WatchedProduct")]
public IEnumerable<WatchedProduct> GetWatchedProduct(string id)
{
    var productsList = id == String.Empty ?
        db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == id).ToList() :
        db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == loggedUserId).ToList();

    return productsList;
}
```

More info [Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

#### EDIT

If your controller name is `WatchedProductController` then you dont need to specify it explicitly. What i am saying is:

```
public class WatchedProduct : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/WatchedProduct
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WatchedProduct> Get(string id)
    {
        var productsList = id == String.Empty ?
        db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == id).ToList() :
        db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == loggedUserId).ToList();

        return productsList;
    }
}
```

should works.

Comment: But i want have oporunity to call `/api/WatchedProduct` and `/api/WatchedProduct/stringid` from one method. Is it possible?

Comment: You can use overloads for that, one for parameterless method and another with `string id` parameter.

Comment: i know that overloading is a easy way to go, but is it possible to have one method with id as a `string`, but return diffrent params (like in my original post)  when stirng is empty? When ID is `int` we can easily make `(int? id) without problems. In my case id is an `string` and i cant make it nullable

Comment: @michasaucer why don't you try with `string id =""`?

Comment: beacuse when i pass "empty" call like `http://localhost:56971/api/WatchedProduct`, without any `id`, i get a json respons like in my original post

Comment: @michasaucer take a look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329724/rest-webapi-uri-get-with-string-instead-of-id-not-routing-as-expected). Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
public class WatchedProduct : ApiController
{
 // GET: api/WatchedProduct
 [HttpGet]
  [Route("WatchedProduct")]
   public IEnumerable<WatchedProduct> Get()
  {
   var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContext;
   var id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
    var productsList = id == String.Empty ?
    db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == id).ToList() :
    db.WatchedProducts.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == loggedUserId).ToList();

    return productsList;
  }
}
```

should work for both the cases as it satisfies both the routes.